# windows directory contents being "." and ".."

Tags: perl

I'm trying to search through the contents of a directory. Inside of the directory is other directories, which should always be in the same order. When I make an array of the directory contents, I have to reserve the first two spots for "." and "..". Can anyone tell me why this is?

And is this present on mac as well? My script won't run properly on mac because the array isn't lining up with where the directories should be. I think its because these "." and ".." spots don't exist on mac or something. I'm just looking for some answers. Not sure if it will help, but here is my code.

```
print "Enter the SMD day folder to generate summary. (Ex: a folder named 06132017)\n";
chomp($smddirectory = <STDIN>);
print "\n";
print "Output will be in the SGE folder.\n";
opendir ($DIR, $smddirectory) ;
my @directories = readdir $DIR;
closedir $DIR;

@directories = map{$smddirectory . '/' . $_} @directories;

$mydir = @directories[14];
$mydirs = @directories[2];
$mydirb = @directories[3];
$mydirbs = @directories[4];
$mydirc = @directories[5];
$mydircs = @directories[6];
$JSHDirectory = @directories[7];
$JSHsDirectory = @directories[8];
$JSHBDirectory = @directories[9];
$JSHBsDirectory = @directories[10];
$JSHCDirectory = @directories[11];
$JSHCsDirectory = @directories[12];
$SGEDirectory = @directories[13];
```

Comment: On Windows, '.' is the current directory, and '..' is the parent directory.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp oh okay thanks, thats what i was thinking. do you know what the case is for mac and linux machines?

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`!!! It will catch that fact that most of your vars are unscoped, and it will tell you that `@directories[14]` should be `$directories[14]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you won't always get `.` and `..`. You'll only get them if they exist in the directory,<sup>[1]</sup> and the reason you get them is because they exist in the directory.<sup>[2]</sup> Just filter them out if you're not interested in them.

```
my @directories =
    map { "$smddirectory/$_" }
       grep { !/^\.\.?\z/ }
          readdir($DIR);
```

Furthermore, there's no guarantee about the order in which `readdir` will return the directory entries. You should not rely on them being in any particular order.

---

1. They root of physical drives don't have `.` or `..` in Windows.

   ```
   >perl -E"opendir($dh, $ARGV[0]) or die $!; say 0+grep /^\./, readdir($dh)" C:\
   0

   >perl -E"opendir($dh, $ARGV[0]) or die $!; say 0+grep /^\./, readdir($dh)" C:\Users
   2
   ```

   It varies for other type of drives.

   ```
   >subst Z: C:\

   >perl -E"opendir($dh, $ARGV[0]) or die $!; say 0+grep /^\./, readdir($dh)" Z:\
   0

   >subst /d Z:

   >subst Z: C:\Users

   >perl -E"opendir($dh, $ARGV[0]) or die $!; say 0+grep /^\./, readdir($dh)" Z:\
   2

   >subst /d Z:
   ```
2. These and other files starting with `.` are normally kept hidden from users in unix systems (incl OS/X), but `ls -a` will show them. `.` is a link to the current directory, and `..` is a link to the parent directory.

Comment: thanks so much, i actually did run into this problem and your answer is very helpful. and you are right about readdir not returning the entries in a specific order, im working on that problem now.

Answer (score -1):

Linux/Unix systems have the same convention, as do newer Macs (from what I'm aware, I don't use one).

One way to get around this issue on all systems by using [grep](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html).

Put the following line right above your `map` line.

```
@directories = grep{$_ !~ /^\.{1,2}$/} @directories;
```

What that will do is rebuild the `@directories` array after removing all entries that are either `.` or `..`.

If you're on a system that doesn't list the `.` or `..` directories, the `grep` line won't do anything.

After that, you can re-index your array back to `0` and it'll work across all of your platforms.

Comment: Technically, that also filters out `.␊` and `..␊`. They're not likely to exist, but it's not very clean to filter them out.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback! I tested it out and this solution works.

Comment: @ikegami I honestly don't understand why that happens. I will play around, but of course would appreciate you explaining why, as always ;)

Comment: @Carson ikegami's answer is much more elaborate and should be chosen as the proper answer.

Comment: @stevieb `$` Match the end of the string (or **before newline at the end
                 of the string**) (emphasis mine)

Comment: `$` without `/m` is equivalent to `(?=\n?\z)`. (`$` with `/m` is equivalent to `(?=\n|\z)`.)